# Better design pattern for reading other process memory?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a cheat for an offline game, and have a class called Player which is responsible for getting and setting values in another process.  However, my design for this class is very poor because the use of the class Player looks very messy and ugly, very difficult to read, and maintain

```
// declare variables here to read
if (Player.getthis() && Player.getthat() && Player.getthat() ... and so on) 
//do stuff

class Player {
...
public:
    ...
    // either of these calls can fail, so I return TRUE on success and FALSE on failure
    BOOL GetHealth(float& health);
    BOOL SetHealth(float& health);  
    ...
};
```

So my question is, what is a better way of doing this?
Also: I don't necessarily need to read every single value of Player in memory, only a few at a time.  That is why I don't have a single method such as BOOL UpdatePlayer() which will read everything and update the player

Comment: Why are you using `BOOL` instead of the `bool` keyword? (Same with `TRUE`/`FALSE` vs `true`/`false`)

Comment: I assume the cheat is for a winapi application.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: With that much code it's impossible to tell what you want to fix and how to fix it.

Comment: @FrankerZ This question in its current form would be closed as off-topic on Code Review.  It isn't considered [real code](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3652/27623).

Comment: He'd need to include his full code @syb0rg, which he's apparently written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
class Player {
public:
    class AccessException : public std::exception {
        friend class Player;
    public:
        virtual const char *what() const noexcept {
            return "Error getting property with key " + key;
        }

    private:
        AccessException(const std::string &key)
            : key(key)
        {}

        std::string key;
    };

    float GetHealth() {
        if (is_error) {
            throw AccessException("health");
        }

        return health;
    }

    float GetPosX() {
        if (is_error) {
            throw AccessException("posX");
        }

        return posX;
    }
};

void do_stuff() {
    try {
        float health = player.GetHealth();
        float posX = player.GetPosX();
        // Use health and posX...
    } catch (const AccessException &ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you added exceptions?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Because this is literally exactly what they were created for.

Comment: for what? I mean... nothing in the OP's question suggest that he needs them.

Comment: @ KarolyHorvath Uh, yes, very much so. Returning a bool to propagate an error is almost always indicative of a need for exceptions.

Comment: Oh, it's in the comment... sorry, I missed it.